# python Flask jinja2 Templating nested mongodb data Cursor object

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Usually I did many times without problems but now it's different and I don't know why .

I'm just trying to display a list on html page using Flask and Jinja2.

And here is my piece of code.

```
__init__.py
    bpPortfolioList = Blueprint('portfolio', __name__)
    @bpPortfolioList.route('/list', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @is_log_in
    def plist():
        portfolio = None
        if session['profile'] == 1:
            print('agent')
            portfolio = mongo.db.users.find({"agentid": session['userid']}, {"portfolio": 1})


        for p in portfolio:
            print(p)

        return render_template('portfolio/list.html', portfolios=portfolio)
```

I have catch the output of portfolio and here is the result :

```
{'_id': 10, 'portfolio': {'id': 8476, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': [{'id': 123456, 'account_type': 'None', 'category': '1', 'owner': None, 'ratio': 100, 'status': '1'}]}}
{'_id': 1}
{'_id': 11, 'portfolio': {'id': 4983, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': []}}
{'_id': 13, 'portfolio': {'id': 1226, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': []}}
{'_id': 15, 'portfolio': {'id': 8786, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': []}}
{'_id': 19, 'portfolio': {'id': 7995, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': []}}
```

Then the HTML :

```
 <tbody>
   {% for p in portfolios %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ p.mode }}</td>
      {% for c in p.accounts %}
         <td>{{ c.id }}</td>
         <td>{{ c.status }}</td>
         <td>{{ c.ratio }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
```

At the result I got nothing, except the table header

Any idea what the problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the return value by `mongo.db.users.find` a generator? If so all your contents are consumed by the `for` statement.  Also, your template may in fact not match up with the data structure, as what is yielded should be accessible via `p['portfolio']['id']` and so on.

Comment: do you think the content has been consumed by for ? how ?

Comment: Try copy/pasting the for loop (so attempt to loop twice over the same `portfolio` assignment) and see if you get twice the output.

Comment: I didn't know that,and it's good to know it. However to get access still does not work. I have tested 'p._id'  it's working fine but p['portfolio']['id']  and p.portfolio.id  does not work

Comment: When I use your suggestion p['portfolio']['id'] I got the following error:  jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'portfolio'

Comment: it's an object not a dictionary

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not with `jinja2` but with the way you're manipulating the result from your query. `pymongo`'s `find` method returns an object of type `Cursor`, which sort of behaves like an iterator, namely once you consume it once, it's exhausted and you cannot iterate it again. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213115/list-comprehension-with-cursor-from-pymongo) may help you understand how the `Cursor` type works. So to get this working, just convert results from the query to a `list`:

`portfolio = list(mongo.db.users.find({"agentid": session['userid']}, {"portfolio": 1}))`

Comment: and how to get nested data access  ?

Comment: once it's a list you can access each element by index, and each element should be an object allowing you to access its attributes with dot notation, just as you are doing in the template

Comment: you mean the html template still appears empty or are you getting a different error?

Comment: using this :  {% for p in portfolios %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ p._id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ p['portfolio'] }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}   works

Comment: and using:  {% for p in portfolios %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ p._id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ p['portfolio'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ p.portfolio.id }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %} gives the same error

Comment: the same error like <td>{{ p['portfolio']['id'] }}</td>

Comment: It seems that the problem in the previous example is that you're mixing dot notation with dictionary syntax, and one of them is failing. My guess is that the dictionary syntax is wrong and everything should be dot notation. If that doesn't work, something you can do to explore how data is being passed on to the template is display `<pre>portfolios</pre>` and comment out the rest so that it doesn't raise errors

Comment: this is what I got on the template : <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x000001D3023CF828>

Comment: that means that the result of the query hasn't ben converted to a list, I suggest you convert the result to a list as I do in my example before manipulating the data

Comment: i got an error using list : TypeError: list() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: However I have convrt the cursor into list using a loop like this :      for p in portfolio:
        pf.append(p)

    return render_template('portfolio/list.html', portfolios=pf)      and I got this : [{'_id': 1}, {'_id': 10, 'portfolio': {'id': 8476, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': [{'id': 123456,.....}]...]

Comment: using this piece of template  : <pre>{{ portfolios }}</pre>
                {% for p in portfolios %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ p._id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ p.portfolio }}</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}

Comment: gives the following result :                                               1  -
10 {'id': 8476, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': [{'id': 123456, account_type': 'None', 'category': '1', 'owner': None,  'ratio': 100, 'status': '1'}]} -
11 {'id': 4983, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': []} -
13 {'id': 1226, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': []} -
15 {'id': 8786, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': []} -
19 {'id': 7995, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': []} -

Comment: And as soon as I add <td>{{ p.portfolio.id }}</td>  I got the same error: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'portfolio'

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out that some document from db has missing attribut like:

portfolio is missing and also accounts are emtpy.

```
{'_id': 10, 'portfolio': {'id': 8476, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': [{'id': 123456, 'account_type': 'None', 'category': '1', 'owner': None, 'ratio': 100, 'status': '1'}]}}
**{'_id': 1}**
{'_id': 11, 'portfolio': {'id': 4983, 'description': '', 'mode': 'Closed', 'accounts': []}}
```

By adding the following code it solves my problem :

```
new_pf = []
    for p in pf:
        if 'portfolio' in p:
            if 'accounts' in p['portfolio'] and p['portfolio']['accounts']:
                new_pf.append(p)
```

Thanks for your support